# Routing React part and ExpressJS

Tags: reactjs, express

This my frontend part:

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/events', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Ошибка при отправке данных');
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            const newEvent = {
                id: data.id,
                event: data.event,
                description: data.description,
            };

            setEvents((prevEvents) => [...prevEvents, newEvent]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Ошибка при отправке запроса:', error);
        }
    };
```

This my backend part:

```
app.post('/events', (req, res) => {
    const { event, description } = req.body;
    const newEvent = {
        id: Math.random(),
        event,
        description,
    };

    DB.events.push(newEvent);

    res.send(newEvent);
});
```

When I add a new event, my react component disappears and this appears:

[image]

I'm trying to get a list of all tasks and a component:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSZKJ.png)

Comment: You missed Express baseUrl here. fetch('/events', ...)

Comment: @Kim Saakyan
Please provide full component code to understant your problem better.